# How to get Object from ArrayList Without loop?

Tags: java, android, oop

Suppose I have a class Employee :

```
class Employee {
         Employee(String name, int age)
         {
             this.name = name ;
             this.age = age;
         }
         String name ;
         int age;
     }
```

Now Create a List of this like :

```
ArrayList<Employee> aa = new ArrayList<Employee>();
 aa.add(new Employee("Nitish", 26));
 aa.add(new Employee("Sh", 2));
 aa.add(new Employee("S", 1));
```

Can i get Employee Object Where name value is "Nitish"? Without For loop

Comment: No you can't without looping. In case you want instant access, you may use Map and store name as key and Employee as value.

Comment: This was interview question

Comment: Generally an interviewer would want to see how quick and confident you are while answering and he should like if you try and suggest an alternate solution. So, the plan answer would be NO, And you could have suggested the usage of Map in case one needs to find without loop.

Comment: Use a Map for o(1) lookups

Comment: Or you can use a stream or method which performs the loop for you but that isn't changing how it behaves.

Comment: It's good to have the reference type of your list as `java.util.List` instead of `ArrayList`, you must considering changing `ArrayList<Employee> aa = new ArrayList<Employee>();` to `List<Employee> aa = new ArrayList<Employee>();`. It's always good to do this without any harm.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your interviewer just doesn't want you to use `for` or `while` loops to find objects in an `ArrayList`, but you can actually find them "without loops".

First, you need to override `equals` and `hashCode` of `Employee` class:

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // ...
}

@Override public int hashCode() {
    // ...
}
```

Now you can find your object with [ArrayList.indexOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) (uses `equals` to find match) by creating a dummy reference:

```
Employee target = new Employee("Nitish", 26);
int index = employees.indexOf(target);
```

It's kinda silly but I guess some interviewers want us to think outside-of-the-box. Even though under the hood it's using loops,  but if my interviewer asks me the same question, instead of saying no you can't, I'd use this example because I want to try my best just not to use "loops" as asked, and explains how it works behind the scene. Then afterwards I'd briefly come up with other better solutions, and hope that works!

Comment: This uses a loop under the covers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I know, but If my interviewer asks me the same question, instead of saying no you can't, I'd use this answer because I do my best not to use "loops" as asked, and explains how it works under the hood. Then afterwards I'd briefly come up with other better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Employee emp = aa.stream().filter(e->e.name.equals("Nitish")).findAny().orElse(null);
```

this version returns null if not found

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filtered stream:

```
Object[] array = aa
        .stream()
        .parallel()
        .filter((emp) -> emp.name.equals("Nitish"))
        .toArray();

if (array.length > 0) {
    Employee employee = (Employee)array[0];
    String name = employee.name;
    int age = employee.age;
    System.out.println("Found Employee with Name = " + name + " and Age = " + age);
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```

Comment: This uses multiple loops under the covers

Comment: *under the covers* is the key word.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList work on index based structure.to ADD,READ,GET value from array need to index of the specific index.
instead store data on ArrayList you can use Map.
Using key can be access value from Map.

```
 Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

    employeeMap.put("Nitish", new Employee("Nitish", 26));
    employeeMap.put("Sh", new Employee("Sh", 2));
    employeeMap.put("S", new Employee("S", 1));

    System.out.println(employeeMap.get("Nitish").getName());
    System.out.println(employeeMap.get("Nitish").getAge());
```